# Logrotate get created file name

Tags: logrotate

I can produce file truncated from original log file with timestamp extention (%y%m%d%s). How can I get the name of created file in order to use this name in 'postrotate'. The following conf file does not work at a time when rotation takes time.

```
/usr/local/apacheHttpServer/logs/mod_jk.log{
missingok
copytruncate
rotate 7
notifempty
sharedscripts
dateext
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
postrotate
   day=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%s)
   cp /usr/local/apacheHttpServer/logs/mod_jk.log-$day  /tmp/truncate/log/
endscript
}
```

Actually there may be several ways to detect the created file. But I assume there should be simple variable keeping this name. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually I have voted all valuable answers clicking up button. Some of them have not been answered yet, some of them has answered only by myself therefore I could not voted it. I believe feedback is the key point of keeping and extending the quality of this web site. I am aware of it. Thanks.

Comment: I honestly forget when this permission comes, since it isn't listed, but you should be able to accept your own answers.

Comment: ok lets talk about my current question :)

Comment: I wish I could, but I can't.  I am unfamiliar with this language; I only commented to assist you in a feature which it appeared you were unaware of.

Comment: I was about to come back here, and try again to convince you to accept viable answers to your questions, only to find that you changed your mind.  So, what changed, if I may ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a wordaround problem that if dateformat is as follows (does not contain seconds). File name can be predicted. But I still do not know if dateformat contains seconds (%s) as well

```
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
```